# lambda calculus reduction with α reduction

Tags: lambda, calculus, reduction

I am trying to complete a lambda calculus reduction but I can't continue after a point. I have to reduce the value "two two" where "two = λfx.f (f x)"

I start writing the following:

```
(λfx.f (f x) two) = λx.two (two x)
                  = λa.two(λfx.f(f x) a)
                  = two(λx.a(a x))
                  = (λfx.f (f x) (λx.a(a x)))
```

After that step I'm starting getting really confused and I'm not sure how to continue. Do I have to apply the second lambda term to the `f` variable of the first lambda term? I tried it but I got not a result.

Answer (score 0):

Let `2 := λfx.f (f x)`, note that

```
 2 a    = λx.a (a x)     (i)
(2 a) b = a (a b)        (ii)
```

thus

```
2 2 
= λx.2 (2 x)             by (i), a = 2
= λxy.(2 x) ((2 x) y)    by (i), a = (2 x)
= λxy.(2 x) (x (x y))    by (ii)
= λxy.x (x (x (x y)))    by (ii)
= λfx.f (f (f (f x)))
=: 4
```

Comment: where the "y" comes from in the second line?